# One if statement taking precedence over another if, despite it being lower?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I'm trying to make an if statement that would allow the user to exit the program by typing quit. My problem lies in that another if statement I have in the same block, albeit lower down, catching to ensure that the string entered is no longer than 3 characters long (required for the program) and that if statement takes precedence and cancels out the "quit" if statement. What am I doing wrong that is causing this?

```
        System.out.print("Guess #"+numGuess+": ");
            guess = input.nextLine();
            guess.toUpperCase();
        if(guess == "quit" || guess == "QUIT"){
            done = true;
            System.out.println("You lose.");
            display();
        }
        if(guess.length() != 3){
            while(guess.length() < 3){
                System.out.println("Guess too short");
                System.out.print("Guess #"+numGuess+": ");
                guess = input.nextLine();
                guess.toUpperCase();
            }
            while(guess.length() > 3){
                System.out.print("Guess too long");
                System.out.print("Guess #"+numGuess+": ");
                guess = input.nextLine();
                guess.toUpperCase();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use `else if(guess.length() != 3){` ... use `else if` to make sure that both the quit and 3 length conditions are not both evaluated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Keep things simple:

1. Make your quitting `if` block `return;` to exit your program (after `disply();`)
2. Don't use `==` to compare strings. Use `.equals()` or better `.equalsIgnoreCase()`

Answer (score -1):

String comparison `if(guess == "quit" || guess == "QUIT")` in your code is wrong.
If you want to compare the contents of a string you have to use `.equals()` method. `==` compares the references not the contents.

Change `if(guess == "quit" || guess == "QUIT")` to `if(guess.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT"))`

Comment: Who ever down-voted an answer should justify a reason behind it. If the answer is wrong, then a comment along with that is a very reasonable and acceptable action. 
I simply don't like my answer down-voted just because the the question is a duplicate.
That does not serve the purpose of down-voting.
Very misleading. Whoever did this should atleast justify

Answer (score -1):

Try simplifying the code a bit.

```
 while (guess.length() != 3) {
    System.out.print("Guess #"+numGuess +": ");
    guess = input.nextLine();
    guess = guess.toUpperCase();

    if(guess.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){
        done = true;
        System.out.println("You lose.");
        display();
        break;
    }

    if (guess.length() < 3){
        System.out.println("Guess too short");
    }
    else if (guess.length() > 3){
        System.out.print("Guess too long");
    }
   numGuess++;
}
```